# Check whether a number contains a pair of combinations which are both primes

Tags: c, recursion, primes

I'm trying to create a boolean recursive function which accepts 1 parameter only and doesn't act as a wrapper for another function, that checks whether a number contains a pair of combinations which are both primes.

For example, the possible combinations for 8379 are:

```
8 379  
83 79  
837 9
```

I've managed to create the function using a wrapper function, but I can't seem to be able to do it without a wrapper.

What I currently have is:

```
func(num):  
num is prime -> return true
else -> call func(num / 10, num % 10).

fun(num1, num2):  
num1 and num2 are primes -> return true  
num1 < 10 -> return false  
return func(num1 / 10, concat(num1 % 10, num2))
```

Comment: Wrapper = Wrapper function. And yeah, this is homework. I'm not looking for code, just general algorithm.

Comment: Might help if you showed us the code you already have, or at least a pseudo-code equivalent (to keep it short).

Comment: have you tried to simply copy the function code into the "wrapper function"? If that's the requirement ...

Comment: Well, the function must accept 1 parameter only, and my solution uses 2 parameters. I can't seem to find a way to make it work using 1 parameter only.

Comment: the function should also return `true` if the number itself is prime? (not some pair of digits)

Comment: @moooeeeep Yes. But again, I'm not asking for a full code, so that's not the issue here really.

Comment: reorganize your main loop into deleting the input number (8379) by 10, 100, 1000... at each step - i.e. for(d=10, ...; d*=10) on each step calculate k1=n/d, k2=n%d - and inside the loop inline all your prime-handling logic. Loop until the number is < d or something. aha, noticed it must be recursive ... hmm. It would naturally be translated into a recursive function of two params - your input n and d. Smething's not right - you have two nums essentially so must have two params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing in Java.

I'm not quite sure if you want to check for "multiple" combinations of the number or just one.

Here's my recursive function for checking just one combination's existence. If I addressed your requirement incorrectly, please leave a comment.

```
public static boolean splitPrime(int n, int pow10) {
        return (isPrime(n / pow10) && isPrime(n % pow10))
                || (pow10  < n/10 && splitPrime(n, pow10 * 10));
    }
```

Invoke it using `splitPrime(n,10)`

Comment: the requirements say the recursive function must accept just 1 (*one*) parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an `isPrime` function defined, then you could define your function like:

```
bool f(int x) {
    int right = x % 10, left = x / 10, iter = 1;

    while (left) {
        if (isPrime(left) && isPrime(right)) return true;

        right = (pow(10, iter++) * (left % 10)) + right;
        left = left / 10;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The function must be recursive, that's why it doesn't seem logical to me that it would only accept one parameter.

Comment: Are you sure the possible combinations of, lets say, 8379, don't include the pair (3, 7)?